# java - How do I remove an object from an ArrayList if a condition is met?

Tags: java

I want to remove some objects (if they meet a condition) of an ArrayList while looping through it. But that will obviously throw a 'ConcurrentModificationException'.

So, what's the best way of doing this?

edit: My condition is a number comparision, so if an objects' variable is greater than a value, the object must be removed from the list..

Comment: Use an Iterator.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8:

```
rooms.removeIf(r -> r.getSize() >= 40) ;
```

Comment: It's not about the name, it's about a variable of the object that determines whether it should be removed or not

Comment: Ok ! edited my answer @Robby

Comment: Oh, gosh how could I miss that. Thanks!